# Is it possible to define class which implements interface without implementation?

Tags: typescript, class, types, interface

Is it possible to define a class which has interface variables without implementation in TypeScript?

For example:

```
interface ITask {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

class Task implements ITask {
  // without implementation
}
```

The above code will cause an error like this:

```
Type 'Task' is missing the following properties from type 'Task', ...
```

I also tried the following code, but it also caused an error:

```
class Task extends ITask {
  // without implementation
}
```

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

I am asking this question because I want to generate classes from interfaces automatically, without changing any variable. I don't want to copy and paste all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of type safety that [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict) gives you.  (If you're not using it, then you should.)  It sounds like you're trying to circumvent some of it and It's not clear to me why you want to do this.  If you convince the compiler that the class has implemented the interface without actually doing so, all you're doing is suppressing compiler warnings that are meant prevent having runtime errors. As it stands, the following code produces compiler warnings:

```
const t: ITask = new Task(); // error here
t.id.toFixed(2);
```

which is a good thing, because at runtime, `t.id` will be `undefined`, so `t.id.toFixed()` will throw an exception.  If you force `Task implements ITask` to work, then you'd get no compiler warnings, but you'd still get a runtime error.

---

If you really want to do this, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to reopen the `Task`'s instance interface and have it extend `ITask`:

```
interface Task extends ITask { } // merging
class Task implements ITask {
}
```

Now there's no error, but of course you run into the same problem here:

```
const t = new Task();
t.id.toFixed() // compiles without error
```

---

If you want to be safe, you could make `Task` implement `Partial<ITask>` using [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to make the properties from `ITask` [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

```
interface Task extends Partial<ITask> { }
class Task implements Partial<ITask> {
}
```

And now the compiler will expect a `Task` to *possibly* have those fields, but you need to check them for nullishness before using them, such as by using the [optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```
const t = new Task();
t.id.toFixed() // compiler error now
t.id?.toFixed(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpDYAFwjQDMFkBJAFRCgGs8jTuyATALiTAArmABG1ANxceJChgoAbCIKgVMwLNOKkAvkRkl4i1lCQt2ZMDGWRKZ5qw4EdsgPRukAdwUALAPbCFFY2EHYUIPL+wIZI+oTxRKCQsPRIAMK+EJHkOC7c5FS0aY6W+bJ8giLiUrHc8koqSGoaWrGJrmSU1HSI5k5IEAAeVMC8DhbOcbHGpv2WGNa2EPZIpc7tBp3w0WpIwQC8QhBe82wAFACU2vVoAJ6cnfUAdBi8zxT+AGIYQxC8VyQHiQO2sGGUZh8FACQUGaDQ-jQ7RBkXgviQ5wgl0eFRBu38ymein8WEx1yBngor14ZDMwjGEBo5H+m06VLeAH4Pt9fv8rpIKUh-GwQHctkQOklwNA4H0AMogGjUR6xQo9EqTHEVN5VUQSNA3CoNZSqdS5Q0kDoFbrFPqa4ajcZIAAKIDQ8hAigAPOsAHx4abbExQMyaxahcJmV3ujCen2Tf3lS1bbg7YB7Q7HU6TfmxdQPJM8dnvT4-P4A7HA0EwcHK6gItBCfxeZHwVHosla2RpqAEiBEklkgXA4u0pD03iM5m8VkvTncst88nA4WirbxIA)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

interface User extends IUser {}
class User {
  constructor(user: IUser) {
    Object.assign(this, user);
  }

  getFullName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const userData: IUser = {
  email: "john@xyz.com",
  phone: "1234567890",
  name: "John Doe",
};

const user = new User(userData);
console.log(user.email); // john@xyz.com
console.log(user.getFullName()); // John Doe
```